# Python regex replace keep string between 2 characters

Tags: python, regex, r, string, wildcard

I have a challenge replacing text in Python with strings, I managed to do a similar replacement with decimals using 
`tocsv = re.sub(r'"(\d+),(\d+)"', r'\1.\2', output)`

I'm looking to replace for example

> "I need to keep this text, but add a double quote at end of this
>   string|

and needs to become

> "I need to keep this text, but add a double quote at end of this
>   string"|

Thanks.

Comment: Can you give us your current code and the current output?

Comment: Does it always end with a "|"?

Answer (score 2):

```
      import re
      x='"I need to keep this text, but add a double quote at end of this string|'
      print re.sub("\|","\"|",x)
```

This gives to desired output.

Comment: Your answer works but now I have an issue as I wanted to keep the piped decimals unquoted, that I didn't mention sorry:  x='5|25|"I need to keep this text, but add a double quote at end of this string|'

Comment: OK, found my solution for this:  print re.sub(r'"(.*?)\|', r'"\g<1>"|', x)